# Tiny MCE editor Font-family restriction is not working

Tags: tinymce, font-family

I need restrict Font-family in Tiny MCE editor but it is not working.

I am using mentioned code but it is not restricting font-family in Tiny MCE editor.

```
font_formats: 'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif',
```

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea#ptn-vendor-pro-page',
    content_security_policy: "default-src 'none'; img-src 'self' *.tinymce.com *.tiny.cloud data: blob:; font-src 'self' *.tinymce.com *.tiny.cloud; connect-src 'self' *.tinymce.com *.tiny.cloud blob:; script-src 'self' *.tinymce.com *.tiny.cloud; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.tinymce.com *.tiny.cloud; frame-src https://player.vimeo.com https://www.youtube.com; media-src https://www-ptn.nblytest.com https://www.youtube.com/;",
    plugins: 'preview importcss searchreplace autolink save directionality code visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap  pagebreak nonbreaking anchor insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount help charmap quickbars emoticons',
    imagetools_cors_hosts: ['picsum.photos'],
    menubar: 'file edit view insert format tools table help',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist | forecolor backcolor removeformat | pagebreak | charmap emoticons | fullscreen  preview save | insertfile image media template link anchor codesample | ltr rtl',
    toolbar_sticky: true,
    autosave_ask_before_unload: false,
    autosave_interval: '30s',
    autosave_prefix: '{path}{query}-{id}-',
    autosave_restore_when_empty: false,
    autosave_retention: '2m',
    image_advtab: true,
    importcss_append: true,
    templates: [
          { title: 'New Table', description: 'creates a new table', content: '<div class="mceTmpl"><table width="98%%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><th scope="col"> </th><th scope="col"> </th></tr><tr><td> </td><td> </td></tr></table></div>' },
      { title: 'Starting my story', description: 'A cure for writers block', content: 'Once upon a time...' },
      { title: 'New list with dates', description: 'New List with dates', content: '<div class="mceTmpl"><span class="cdate">cdate</span><br /><span class="mdate">mdate</span><h2>My List</h2><ul><li></li><li></li></ul></div>' }
    ],
    template_cdate_format: '[Date Created (CDATE): %m/%d/%Y : %H:%M:%S]',
    template_mdate_format: '[Date Modified (MDATE): %m/%d/%Y : %H:%M:%S]',
    height: 600,
    image_caption: true,
    quickbars_selection_toolbar: 'bold italic | quicklink h2 h3 blockquote quickimage quicktable',
    noneditable_noneditable_class: 'mceNonEditable',
    toolbar_mode: 'sliding',
    contextmenu: 'link image imagetools table',
    skin: useDarkMode ? 'oxide-dark' : 'oxide',
    content_css: useDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'default',
    content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }',
    init_instance_callback: "customTinyMceInit",
    setupcontent_callback : "myCustomSetupContent",
    relative_urls : false,
    convert_urls : false,
    font_formats: 'Arial=arial,helvetica',
    font_size_formats: '8pt 10pt',
    // color_map: [
    //   '000000', 'Black',
    //   '808080', 'Gray',
    // ]
   })
```

Please suggest what is mistake in code.